# Generalize print+format for a variable number of inputs

Tags: python, pretty-print

If I have a 3-tuple of floats, and I want to print them formatted, I can do:

```
print('{:.2f} {:.2f} {:.2f}'.format(*my_tuple))
```

And if I have an n-tuple of floats, I can use a map and achieve the same formatting with:

```
print(*map(lambda x: '{:.2f}'.format(x), my_tuple))
```

I was wondering, though, **if there is a way of changing the `print` function itself so that it already does the formatting I want** for floats without any extra intervention. I couldn't find anything about that in the docs.

*I'd like to have a simple*
`print(*my_tuple)` *that would work also in cases where not all terms in the tuple are floats.*

I am asking this question because it seems like I should be able to tweak `print`, so I feel I'm missing something simple here.

Comment: can you provide an input-output example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply define your own? Like so:

```
def my_print(data):
    print(', '.join('{:.2f}'.format(x) if type(x)==float else str(x) for x in data))

my_print((1.23, 51212., 5.151252, 1.25, 125.1545, .5314451, 5.1251, 5,.125 , 'sdgsdgdsg'))
# prints:
# 1.23, 51212.00, 5.15, 1.25, 125.15, 0.53, 5.13, 5, 0.12, sdgsdgdsg
```

After all you would not want to change or redefine the way `print()` works and you don't have to..

Comment: +1, could do `print(*('{:.2f}'.format(x) if type(x)==float else str(x) for x in data))` for closer syntax to the OP

Comment: Yes, this seems like the way to go... But I expected some sort of defaults that I could change for print, without having to call my own `my_print` everytime. Also, today I may want `:.2f`, tomorrow `:.4f`. Today I may want to print to stdout, tomorrow to a file, etc.

Comment: @you probably have a `numpy` background or something similar where you can set the way floats are represented. for example, there you can do something like `np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float': '{:.2f}'.format})`. All successive prints will then follow this rule for floats. I do not know how this is implemented though.